# django - Upload page must only be accessible once the form is submitted. Directly entering the upload url should not work

Tags: django

Uploading a file is only allowed once the form is submitted. The upload url must not be accessible otherwise.

After the user logs in, the upload url is directly accessed. How can i restrict this? This will create multiple entries of file upload for the same form

models.py

```
class uploadmeta(models.Model):
    path = models.ForeignKey(Mdform, verbose_name="ID", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    datafile = models.FileField(upload_to=get_upload_folder, verbose_name="Dataset", validators=[validate_file_extension])

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('file_list', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

views.py

````
        if request.user.is_authenticated:

                if request.method == 'POST':
                        form = uploadmetaform(request.POST, request.FILES)

                        if form.is_valid():
                                path = form.cleaned_data['path']
                                if uploadmeta.objects.filter(path=path).exists():
                                        user = form.cleaned_data['user']
                                        datafile = form.cleaned_data['datafile']
                                        context = {
                                        'path': path,
                                        'user': user,
                                        'datafile': datafile  
                                        }
                                        template = loader.get_template('nameexists.html')
                                        return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
                                else:
                                        user = form.cleaned_data['user']
                                        datafile = form.cleaned_data['datafile']
                                        path = dict(form.fields['path'].path)[path]
                                        print(path)
                                        b = form(path=path, user=user, datafile=datafile)
                                        b.save()
                                        context = {
                                        'path': path,
                                        'user': user,
                                        'datafile': datafile
                                        }
                                        template = loader.get_template('thankyou.html')
                                        return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
                        else:
                               form = uploadmetaform()

                        return render(request, 'uploaddata.html', {'form': form})
        else:
                return render(request, 'home.html')```
````

Comment: You can use models...map the form field to a DB field store the value and check for value in the database....If the value exists then throw `data already present`

Comment: could you please give me an example of how to do this?

Comment: https://gitlab.com/ybagarka/ormuco-code.git

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but i am too illerate to apply this code in mine. i tried editing it. But still when enter the upload url it allows to upload again

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from basicform.forms import BasicForm
from django.template import loader
from django.http import HttpResponse
from basicform.choices import * 

from basicform.models import BasicFormModel


def responseform(request):
     if request.method == 'POST':
        basicForm = BasicForm(request.POST)

        if basicForm.is_valid():
            name = basicForm.cleaned_data['name']
            if BasicFormModel.objects.filter(name=name).exists():
                favourite_color = basicForm.cleaned_data['favourite_color']
                choices = basicForm.cleaned_data['choices']    
                context = {
                'name': name,
                'favourite_color': favourite_color,
                'choices': choices
                }
                template = loader.get_template('nameexists.html')
                return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
            else:
                favourite_color = basicForm.cleaned_data['favourite_color']  
                choices = basicForm.cleaned_data['choices'] 
                print("cleanded choices="+choices)
                choices = dict(basicForm.fields['choices'].choices)[choices]
                print(choices)
                b = BasicFormModel(name=name, favourite_color=favourite_color, choices=choices)
                b.save()
                context = {
                'name': name,
                'favourite_color': favourite_color,
                'choices': choices
                }
                template = loader.get_template('thankyou.html')
                return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))


     else:
         form = BasicForm()

     return render(request, 'responseform.html', {'form':form});
```

Comment: i tried something with a raw sql statement, could you help me correct this? updating my question

Comment: Raw SQL statement is not needed..you will create models and import that in your views....refer the models.py in gitlab..then you will call the model object with name field then use the form data for name field and check that against the db for me the db was ppstgree

Comment: thanks, i referred to your modely.py and edited my code i am now getting this error: The view views.uploaddata didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

Comment: @user11603936 kindlt share the git link of your code.

Comment: i have just added the code to my question, hope that would help. thanks

Comment: `else:
                return render(request, 'home.html')` this is not needed I guess..try removing this else condition

Comment: i solved the error - didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead. was an indentation error. Now i am getting an error at the else part: KeyError at /uploaddata/

'user'

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/202199/django?tab=general

Comment: are there any validators i could use to achieve this? i want to avoid multiple uploads for the same ID

Comment: I solved it -- it was just too simple, added unique=true in the models for path